# "Another app is using the camera" when trying to turn on the camera or flash

Tags: samsung, camera, flashlight

My Samsung Galaxy J4+ is having a problem. When I turn on the camera or flash, it is saying "Another app is using the camera". But I have checked nothing in the background is using these, and my flash is working only in accessibility settings (Flashing when getting notification)

I have tried restart and safe boot, but nothing works.

How to fix this?

Comment: Could be a hardware defect that makes the camera unavailable and Android thinks it is just used by another app. If you don't get other comments or answers the only option is to perform a factory reset. If that does not help most likely the camera is defect and need to be replaced.

Comment: @Robert i have done soft reset and hard reset nothing

Comment: can you confirm whether your device is running stock or custom rom?

Comment: Stock model samsung j415f android 9